# Julia: installing Winston error need tk8.6

Tags: julia

I'm getting an error = `ERROR: TclError("error initializing Tk: version conflict for package \"Tcl\": have 8.5.15, need 8.6")`while installing the package Winston for Julia.

this is my stack trace

```
 julia> using Winston
    ERROR: TclError("error initializing Tk: version conflict for package \"Tcl\": have 8.5.15, need 8.6")
     in init at /home/laptop/.julia/v0.2/Tk/src/tkwidget.jl:61
     in include at boot.jl:238
     in include_from_node1 at loading.jl:114
     in include at boot.jl:238
     in include_from_node1 at loading.jl:114
     in reload_path at loading.jl:140
     in _require at loading.jl:58
     in require at loading.jl:46
     in include at boot.jl:238
     in include_from_node1 at loading.jl:114
     in include at boot.jl:238
     in include_from_node1 at loading.jl:114
     in reload_path at loading.jl:140
     in _require at loading.jl:58
     in require at loading.jl:43
    at /home/laptop/.julia/v0.2/Tk/src/tkwidget.jl:452
    at /home/laptop/.julia/v0.2/Tk/src/Tk.jl:25
    at /home/laptop/.julia/v0.2/Winston/src/tk.jl:1
    at /home/laptop/.julia/v0.2/Winston/src/Winston.jl:2699
```

ubuntu 14.04
I autoremoved julia and I install it back but the error remains.

Comment: Within Julia, have you tried `Pkg.update()` and `Pkg.build("Tk")`? Perhaps post the output from those commands if the problem persists after running them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had the same problem and found that I've got both 8.5 and 8.6 installed on my system and that the installer somehow managed to use the wrong library. (There already [is a bug filed against Tk.jl for this](https://github.com/JuliaLang/Tk.jl/issues/80).)

The filename is hardcoded in a file named `deps.jl` in some path below your `~/.julia` directory. Running

```
sed -i -re 's#libtcl8.5.so#libtcl8.6.so#' ~/.julia/v0.3/Tk/deps/deps.jl
```

to alter Julia's configuration file should do the trick.